# Invalid credentials when trying to obtain box api tokens

Tags: curl, oauth, box-api

Here is my problem:

I followed the instructions posted at you tube: "Get Box Access Tokens in 2 Quick Steps", using the `client_id` and `client_secret`provided by box

step1: get the `auth_code`

I copy and paste the following request in firefox:

https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&state=authenticated

step2: use the code from step1 to get the access and refresh tokens, using curl:

```
curl -v -k https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code={auth_code}&client_id={MY_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={MY_CLIENT_SECRET}' -X POST
```

The reponse I get is "invalid client credentials". Did I miss something?
Thanks in advance for helping. I really don't know how to troubleshoot this error.

Comment: How long did it take you between step1 and step2?

Comment: You need to be quick - "Authorization Code: The authorization code is only valid for 30 seconds." http://developers.box.com/oauth/

Comment: What's more likely is that you've left in something that's causing the curl request to only take in the first line, ignoring "-d..." and beyond. If you're too slow, you'll actually get this error: {"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The authorization code has expired"}

Comment: If the content is application/json how would we avoid the curly braces. I am seeing the same issue.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51064621/invalid-credentials-while-doing-a-curl-post

Answer (score 0):

What's more likely is that you've left in something that's causing the curl request to only take in the first line, ignoring "-d..." and beyond. If you're too slow, you'll actually get this error:

{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"The authorization code has expired"}

Write the curl request again on one line or try to copy and paste this:

curl https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code={CODE}&client_id={CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={CLIENT_SECRET}' 
-X POST

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it worked for me after adding header:
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

So your curl command would look like

curl -v -k https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code={auth_code}&client_id={MY_CLIENT_ID}&client_secret={MY_CLIENT_SECRET}' -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -X POST

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer my own question in case some other newcomer falls in the same trap as I did:
   Simply remove the curly brackets ({ }), so that the request will be:

```
curl -v https://www.box.com/api/oauth2/token -d 'grant_type=authorization_code&code=AUTH_CODE&client_id=CLIENT_ID&client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET' -X POST
```

and replace `AUTH_CODE`, `CLIENT_ID` and `CLIENT_SECRET` by their corresponding values *without* adding any "decorative" character, at least if you're using curl.

Notice that I also removed the -k option after adding the path to a `cacert.pem` file as a `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variable, so that curl would find it and stop complaining.