# "Invalid credentials" while doing a curl POST

Tags: shell, rest, curl, post, jenkins

I have a curl request in below format

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "x-user-id:xxx" -H "x-api-key:yyy" --data '{"logs":"'"${TEST_OUTPUT}"'","pass":"true | false"}' https://razeedash.one.qqq.cloud.com/api/v1/clusters/zzz/api/test_results
```

This works fine while I do from my MAC terminal. But the same command throws

```
13:49:26 {
13:49:26   "status": "error",
13:49:26   "message": "Invalid credentials"
13:49:26 }
```

I saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20937478/invalid-credentials-when-trying-to-obtain-box-api-tokens) but not sure how else would I send a json body without curly braces. I know that we can save it as a file.json and use the file as body.But for some reasons that cannot be implemented in my scenario

Comment: The error suggest the problem is with one of your headers, not the JSON payload.

Comment: 15:13:12 > Content-Length: 0
Whereas from MAC terminal it shows > Content-Length: 35

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should avoid trying to build JSON using string interpolation. Use a tool like `jq` to handle any necessary quoting.

```
jq -n --argson o "$TEST_OUTPUT" '{logs: $o, pass: "true | false"}' |
    curl -v -H "Content-Type:application/json" \
            -H "x-user-id:xxx" \
            -H "x-api-key:yyy" \
            --data @- \
            https://razeedash.one.qqq.cloud.com/api/v1/clusters/zzz/api/test_results
```

However, if you can manage to correctly generate your JSON as you are now, you can just replace the `jq` command with `echo`:

```
echo '{"logs": ...' | curl ...
```

The `@-` argument to `--data` says to read from standard input.